# map correct id to unique identifier in shp file coordinates

Tags: r, gis, rgdal

I have a shapefile, http://census.cso.ie/censusasp/saps/boundaries/Census2011_Small_Areas_generalised20m.zip

and want to extract the long/lat, but I am not sure how to map the correct coordinate to the correct small area.

mycode is:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(proj4)
require(rgdal)

a=readOGR(....shp)
dublin = a[a$NUS3NAME=='Dublin',]
dublin=spTransform(dublin,CRS('=proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84'))
b=data.frame(dublin)

sa=fortify(dublin,SA='SMALL_AREA')
pj=project(sa[,1:2],proj4string(dublin),inverse=TRUE)
latlon=data.frame(latdeg=pj$y,londeg=pj$x)
sa=data.frame(cbind(latlon,sa)
```

[image]

The number of unique `sa$id` (4500) is the same as the number of unique `b$SMALL_AREA` (4500 rows). How is (for example) and id of 22 mapped from `sa` to the correct small area in `b`?

there are 56k rows in sa and 4500 rows in b

Any suggestions are appreciated

I am working in R

Answer (score 0):

Shapefiles are much easier to work with and understand using the `sf` package in R.  It keeps things tidy and rectangular, with the added `$geometry` list-column.

For your example, getting the lat & lon for the Dublin area:

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

a <- read_sf('Census2011_Small_Areas_generalised20m/Census2011_Small_Areas_generalised20m.shp')

# dplyr filter() works for sf objects
dublin <- a %>% filter(NUTS3NAME == 'Dublin')

# Tranform to WGS84 coordinates
dublin <- dublin %>% st_transform(st_crs(4326))

# Proof CRS has changed
st_crs(dublin)

# lat/lon coords
st_coordinates(dublin) %>% head()
```

In this case, the sf geometry is of MULTIPOLYGON type.  Each observation has between 4 and 168 connected lat/lon points associated with it.  If you are interested in a single point for each observation, the centroid might be a good approximation.

Using `dublin %>% st_centroid()` will return all the data, but with the `$geometry` column consisting of a single point.  Getting just the centroid points (as a matrix) can be achieved using `dublin %>% st_centroid %>% st_coordinates()`.

Finally, a plot of the Dublin subset of the shapefile & the respective centroid points.  There are quite a few shapes in a small area, making things hard to see.  In the outskirts with larger polygons the centroids should be more visible.

```
dublin %>% 
  st_centroid() %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_sf( size = .4, color = '#FF7900')  + 
  geom_sf(data = dublin, 
          color = '#009A49', 
          fill = NA, 
          size = .2) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "black")) +
  coord_sf(datum = NA)
```

[image]